# Using LaTeX in an educational game

Tags: packages

This question is a little abstract. I found LaTeX recently when looking for a typesetting tool for my educational app. Memories of using it years ago during my physics degree and reading about it when learning about computer graphics came back quickly.

**Matchoo!** is a game that's designed primarily around matching images and text. Modes include simple drag and drop operations, or physics and more gamey arcade style level. The users can create packages that combine gameplay with their content.

I'm using LaTeX to allow users to add chemical equations, guitar chords or music phrases. The app squirts their markup to my backend which returns an image for the game modes to use. You can see a very simple example below.

Right now Matchoo gameplay works best with smallish data - the example gives you some idea.

Now - I came to LaTeX specifically for mathematical and chemical equations but have been pretty impressed by the depth of content. I'm **looking for inspiration** on what can be done in LaTeX and what packages would be good for me to look at. Examples might be UML flow diagrams, music (I'm looking at `gchords` and beyond), electrical diagrams, architectural models.

- What packages provide easy typesetting for my small image rather than large document requirement?
- What packages exist that would allow me to extend my users ability to author learning packages with minimal learning of markup languages?

So far I'm using `mhchem`, `pgfplots` and `amsmath` - experimenting with `gchord` and `musixguit`.

Thanks for any suggestions!

[image]

Comment: Welcome! This is not really a good question for this particular site's format. It is likely to elicit primarily opinion-based answers. It is either too broad or unclear or , possibly, both. We don't even know what you are using now. We don't know what you want to do. Why do you want to add any packages at all? You add packages because you want something they offer. But what is wrong with what you have now? Fairly clearly, most of what can be done in LaTeX is entirely irrelevant to you as you seem to be typesetting only snippets. Can you edit your question to explain what you want exactly?

Comment: Thank you for the swift response @cfr. Because of my specific use of latex (combined with my currently very basic understanding of how to author) it's a little tricky for me to work out if a given package will or won't provide added benefit easily - so far it seems to take me a couple of hours with a package to get an idea of it being useful in my context. The scope of what exists is also a little daunting! I edited the question a little to see if it helps.

Comment: Look at `tikz` and also use the `standalone` document class.